# Jquery UI slider not visible in view - Ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-slider

I have been trying to include jquery UI slider in my rails app (rails 4.2.1), but it is not visible when running the app on local host.

**My application.js file:**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree
```

**application.css file:**

```
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
```

**static.js file:**

```
$('#slider').slider({
range: true,
values: [17, 67]
});
```

**static/index.html.erb file:**

```
<div id="slider"></div> <br/>
```

I'm new to rails and tried searching and applying different solutions, yet not able to figure out what's wrong. It will be great if I could get some help on how to make the slider visible?

Comment: does it throw any exception in your browser console?

Comment: Any error in browser console ?

Comment: are you able to see any JS error in your browser console? If not then just do inspect element via browser's developer tool to check whether your slider is getting initialized properly or not.

Comment: I checked, no errors!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should be wrapped inside the ready event:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#slider').slider({
    range: true,
    values: [17, 67]
  });
});
```